# aws embedded c SDK unable to connect with aws iot

Tags: c, amazon-web-services, embedded-linux, raspberry-pi3, aws-iot

Greeting for the days..

I need some help from you all actually after 10 days of leave i am back with my work and i found there are some changes in aws iot console for registering a device(thing) on aws iot. While registering a device on cloud i am getting only Node.js, Java and python SDks but i need embedded c sdk please help me to get embedded c sdk. If i am trying to use my previous embedded c sdk(or from github embedded c sdk)  then i am getting error like this

> "ERROR: main L#176 Error(-4) connecting to a32na51unlbk0b.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:8883" and some time like this "ERROR: main L#176 Error(-28) connecting to a32na51unlbk0b.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:8883".

I am using aws embedded c sdk with raspberry pi3. Previously sdk was working properly but no longer now.

Answer (score 0):

From the SDK documentation this looks like, SSL Connection error.
I hope you are not using the right certificate files to connect to aws,

http://aws-iot-device-sdk-embedded-c-docs.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/aws__iot__error_8h.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems it can't find your endpoint.

First check your endpoint from console or CLI. Then check if you set it correct in `AWS_IOT_MQTT_HOST` in `aws_iot_config.h`.